# how do you compute the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{4n-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, pointwise-convergence, conditional-convergence

I know that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{4n-3}$  is convergent by Leibniz's law. However, finding the exact sum of this series can be quite challenging.

I try to evaluate out to $10$ terms is $0.861229$; $20$ terms is $0.863979$. Would you please share me a way to solve this question?

Best wishes,

Comment: Not everything has a pleasant closed formulation...[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2F%284n-3%29%2C%7Bn%2C+1%2C+infinity%7D%5D) is WA's evaluation of the sum.  Note that it is clearly negative.

Comment: @lulu isn't $-\log(\cot(\pi/8))/ 2\sqrt{2}-\pi/4\sqrt{2}$ a nice value ?

Comment: @Atmos  Yeah, that one's not bad.  Odd that they don't lead with it.

Comment: The simplest way is to notice that the denominators are 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, .. and to look into the second formula in https://doi.org/A016813 .

Comment: @R.J.Mathar the DOI is not found. Do you mean OEIS?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A016813. (And why cannot I correct my previous post?????)

Answer (score 7):

Take the partial sums
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n+1}=-\sum_{n=0}^N\int_0^1 (-x^4)^ndx=-\int_0^1\frac{1-(-x^4)^{N+1}}{1+x^4}dx. $$
Now,
$$ \left|\int_0^1\frac{(-x^4)^{N+1}}{1+x^4}dx\right|\leqslant\int_0^1 x^{4N+4}dx=\frac{1}{4N+5}\underset{N\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$
so, letting $N\rightarrow +\infty$, we get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n+1}=-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^4}. $$
To compute the above integral, you can brute-force with partial fraction decomposition, this gives calculations I don't have the courage to write down (though you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZFQNsy3p1U) video for details), but in the end you get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n+1}=-\frac{\pi+2\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{4\sqrt{2}}. $$

Comment: Thank you! It is a nice solution!